# django filefield issue

Tags: django, formfield

filefield works just fine in the admin, but in a template nothing is uploaded upon submit.  the form comes back with a "required" error for the filefield.

the paths seem to be right, and if they weren't, I don't think filefield would be working in the admin.

spent hours on this and I'm stumped.  I'm using trunk.  Ideas?

Comment: Does it work with 1.1? Trunk isn't usually broken, but sometimes it is and the docs are often behind a bit.

Comment: can you post some bits of the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files

Got it.  I wasn't sending in request.FILES to the modelform constructor.

The django model reference for filefield doesn't mention special consideration for binding uploaded files to a form, but then again, I'm a total noob.  Hopefully this helps someone else!